# accessing xml property using php

Tags: php, simplexml

In an xml respone below

```
<response>
  <lst name="responseHeader">
    <int name="status">0</int>
    <int name="QTime">1</int>
  </lst>
  <lst name="initArgs">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="config">../conf/dataconfig.xml</str>
    </lst>
  </lst>
  <str name="status">busy</str>
  <str name="importResponse">A command is still running...</str>
  <lst name="statusMessages">
    <str name="Time Elapsed">0:0:7.942</str>
    <str name="Total Requests made to DataSource">1</str>
    <str name="Total Rows Fetched">8831</str>
    <str name="Total Documents Processed">8830</str>
    <str name="Total Documents Skipped">0</str>
    <str name="Full Dump Started">2013-06-03 22:15:11</str>
  </lst>
  <str name="WARNING">
    This response format is experimental. It is likely to change in the future.
  </str>
</response>
```

I need to access two values:

```
<str name="status">busy</str>  --  busy
<str name="Total Rows Fetched">8831</str>  --  8831
```

Using code below:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string); 
echo $xml->str[0];
```

I am able to access value *"busy"* but I don't know how to access *"8831"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Xpath:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assuming XML in $x
echo $xml->xpath("//str[@name='status']")[0];
```

and do the same with the other value.

Comment: need solution using simplexml_load_string ?

Comment: yes, it's simplexml, see my edit.

Comment: Awesome solution .... heads off

Answer (score 0):

Use **var_dump($xml);**  to understand xml object. Read Example #1 Interpret an XML string example http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php
It will be something like,

```
foreach($xml->foo[0]->attributes() as $a => $b) { 
      if($a=="Total Rows Fetched"){
         echo $b;    
      }    
  }
```

Comment: its giving A command is still running...[

Comment: not able to do it :-(
please help